# How to update store everytime local storage updated in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, mern

I am a beginner MERN learn. I am creating a simple mern project which is blog where user can create account, login and logout itself. When i login first it say store is null but when i refresh page it show current user data, i tried everything but did't not work anything.

**Store.js.**

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

const URL = writable("http://localhost:8080/auth/registeration");
let user = writable(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")));

export { URL, user };
```

**Login.svelte**

```
<script>
    import axios from "axios";
    import { user } from "../store";
    import { URL } from "../store.js";
    import { link, push } from "svelte-spa-router";

    let email;
    let password;
    let error;
    const login = async () => {
        const obj = {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        };
        try {
            const result = await axios.post(`${$URL}/Login`, obj);
            const token = result.data.token;
            if (result.data.massage === "Successfully login") {
                push("/Deshboard");
                document.cookie = `token=${token}`;
                const userData = result.data.others;
                saveTolocal(userData);
            } else {
                error = result.data.massage;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            error = error.massage;
        }
    };

    const saveTolocal = (userData) => {
        const store = localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(userData));
        console.log($user);
    };
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Login.</h2>
        <form on:submit|preventDefault={login}>
            <div class="UserAndLastName inline">
                <div class="email">
                    <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        id="Email"
                        autocomplete="off"
                        required
                        bind:value={email}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="PasswordAndHobbies inline">
                <div class="password">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        id="password"
                        required
                        placeholder="Password"
                        bind:value={password}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
        {#if error}
            <h3 class="red">{error}</h3>
        {/if}
        <a href="/" use:link>Did't have an account?</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Logout.svelte**

```
const logout = async () => {
    const token = document.cookie;
    const real_token = token.slice(token.indexOf("=") + 1);
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = real_token;
    const result = await axios.post(`${$URL}/Logout`);
    if (result.data.massage == "Logout successful") {
        document.cookie = "token=null";
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(null));
        push("/Login");
    }
};
```

Comment: Just update the store manually at the same time `user.set(userData)`    There is an event on storage you can attach too, but this only works between multiple tabs, so making store auto-update on localeStorage change is not possible.

Comment: @Keith: That is more answer than comment.

Comment: @H.B.   Yeah, it's more me doubting myself.  I don't use svelte so I wasn't 100% sure if there was a more elegant way than just manually updating the store..  Maybe a store that's already backed by localeStorage etc..  So was kind of waiting on others, and if no other users responded it would still be of use to OP.

Comment: Oh, a quick search found this -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-local-storage-store   Maybe that will help the OP.

Comment: Related or potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75050813/546730